# How to fetch all the size of the records in elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am trying to get all the records from the index the issue i am having is that i cannot get all the reocrds using Scroll

```
 var SearchRequest = new SearchRequest<Acquirer>("acquiringdata")
                {

                    From = 0,
                    Size = 10,

                    scroll="1m",

                Query = new BoolQuery
                    {
                        Must = filters,
                        Filter = filterClause
                        
                    }
                };

                var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Acquirer>(SearchRequest);
```

This is what i am getting in json Query i want to get all the records using scroll its not working I am newbie to Elasticsearch any help would be appreciated

```
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "TRANSACTIONDATE": {
              "format": "yyyy||MM",
              "gte": "05",
              "lt": "2019",
              "time_zone": "+01:00",
              "boost": 1.1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "MERCHANTNO": [
              "962425411201011",
              "962215992201005"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like you're doing a scroll query. check out: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/scrolling-documents.html

Comment: @mikeb can you please see this url i have asked a new question by following the link you have given me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63159137/scroll-query-is-not-working-elastic-search