# Scroll Query is not working Elastic Search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

This is my Elastic Search Query for Obtaining the desired output the only reason i am using sroll is that i am having multiple reocrds and i am getting only some records limited by the size i want to get all the records

```
 filters.Add(new TermsQuery
                {

                    Field = new Field("MERCHANTNO"),
                    Terms = BranchCode,
                   

                });
              
                filterClause.Add(new DateRangeQuery
                {
                    Boost = 1.1,
                    Field = new Field("TRANSACTIONDATE"),
                    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Anchored(Date).RoundTo(DateMathTimeUnit.Month),
                    Format = "yyyy-MM",
                    TimeZone = "+01:00"
                });

                var SearchRequest = new SearchRequest<Acquirer>("acquiringdata")
                {

                    Size = 2,
                    Scroll=10,         //I have Tried
                    Scroll="10s"       //I have tried this
                    Scroll=1m           //I have tried this

                Query = new BoolQuery
                    {
                        Must = filters,
                        Filter = filterClause
                        
                    }
                };

                var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Acquirer>(SearchRequest);
                if (searchResponse.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    var requestJson = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
                    var JsonFormatQuery = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestJson), Formatting.Indented);
                }
                while (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
                {
                    //ProcessResponse(searchResponse);
                    searchResponse = _elasticClient.Scroll<Acquirer>("10s", searchResponse.ScrollId);
                }
```

It is giving me empty array when i just Removed these While Loop it gives me the desired output the Size of 10 which i have asked for

```
  while (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
                {
                    //ProcessResponse(searchResponse);
                    searchResponse = _elasticClient.Scroll<Acquirer>("10s", searchResponse.ScrollId);
                }
```

This is my Json i got from the Query and i not getting the point that Scroll is not coming in the Query when i have declared it

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "TRANSACTIONDATE": {
              "format": "yyyy-MM",
              "gte": "2019-10||/M",
              "time_zone": "+01:00",
              "boost": 1.1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 2
}
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with the `searchResponse` that you're not showing in your code? You need to pull the documents out of it and into something else to build up a list of the fetched documents.

Comment: Yes @mikeb it is working as you have said